# Is it possible to get a good stack trace with .NET async methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stack-trace, async-await

I have the following sample code setup in a WebApi application:

```
[HttpGet]
public double GetValueAction()
{
    return this.GetValue().Result;
}

public async Task<double> GetValue()
{
    return await this.GetValue2().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task<double> GetValue2()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't get value!");
}
```

Sadly, when GetValueAction gets hit, the stack trace that comes back is:

```
    " at MyProject.Controllers.ValuesController.<GetValue2>d__3.MoveNext() in c:\dev\MyProject\MyProject\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 61 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at MyProject.Controllers.ValuesController.<GetValue>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\dev\MyProject\MyProject\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 56"
```

Thus, I get (mangled) GetValue2 and GetValue in the trace, but no mention of GetValueAction. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another pattern that will get me more complete stack traces?

EDIT: my goal is not to write code relying on the stack trace, but instead to make failures in async methods easier to debug.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx) on async causality chains.

Comment: Not directly an answer, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28633192/868227) gives a hint how to decipher original method given async stack frame.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This question and its highest voted answer were written back in 2013. Things have improved since then.

.NET Core 2.1 now provides intelligible async stack traces out of the box; see [Stacktrace improvements in .NET Core 2.1](https://www.ageofascent.com/2018/01/26/stack-trace-for-exceptions-in-dotnet-core-2.1/).

For those still on .NET Framework, there's an excellent NuGet package that fixes up async (and many other obscurities) in stack traces: [Ben.Demystifier](https://github.com/benaadams/Ben.Demystifier). The advantage of this package over other suggestions is that it doesn't require changes to the throwing code or assembly; you simply have to call `Demystify` or `ToStringDemystified` on the caught exception.

Applying this to your code:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't get value!
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValue2()
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at void System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(bool includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at TResult System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
   at TResult System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
   at double ValuesController.GetValueAction()
   at void Program.Main(string[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't get value!
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValue2()
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValue()<---
```

This is admittedly still a bit convoluted due to your use of `Task<T>.Result`. If you convert your `GetValueAction` method to async (in the spirit of [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)), you would get the expected clean result:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Couldn't get value!
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValue2()
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValue()
   at async Task<double> ValuesController.GetValueAction()
```

Comment: It's not showing the line number still on Xamarin.Forms.UWP

Comment: For line numbers you need to include the .pdb file (or embedded debugging info)

Comment: @BenAdams I could not get this package working in Mono C# (Unity 2020)

Answer (score 43):

First off, stack traces don't do what most people think they do. They can be useful during debugging, but are not intended for runtime use, particularly on ASP.NET.

Also, the stack trace is technically about *where the code is returning to*, not *where the code came from*. With simple (synchronous) code, the two are the same: the code always returns to whatever method called it. However, with asynchronous code, those two are different. Again, the stack trace tells you what will happen *next*, but you're interested in what happened in the *past*.

So, the stack frame is not the correct answer for your needs. [Eric Lippert explains this well in his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368508/263693).

The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx) that @ColeCampbell linked to describes one way to track "casuality chains" (where the code came *from*) with `async` code. Unfortunately, that approach is limited (e.g., it doesn't handle fork/join scenarios); however, it is the only approach I know of that does work in Windows Store applications.

Since you're on ASP.NET with the full .NET 4.5 runtime, you have access to a more powerful solution for tracking casuality chains: the logical call context. Your `async` methods do have to "opt in", though, so you don't get it for free like you would with a stack trace. I just wrote this up in a blog post that is not yet published, so you're getting a preview. :)

You can build a "stack" of calls yourself around the logical call context as such:

```
public static class MyStack
{
  // (Part A) Provide strongly-typed access to the current stack
  private static readonly string slotName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
  private static ImmutableStack<string> CurrentStack
  {
    get
    {
      var ret = CallContext.LogicalGetData(name) as ImmutableStack<string>;
      return ret ?? ImmutableStack.Create<string>();
    }
    set { CallContext.LogicalSetData(name, value); }
  }

  // (Part B) Provide an API appropriate for pushing and popping the stack
  public static IDisposable Push([CallerMemberName] string context = "")
  {
    CurrentStack = CurrentStack.Push(context);
    return new PopWhenDisposed();
  }
  private static void Pop() { CurrentContext = CurrentContext.Pop(); }
  private sealed class PopWhenDisposed : IDisposable
  {
    private bool disposed;
    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (disposed) return;
      Pop();
      disposed = true;
    }
  }

  // (Part C) Provide an API to read the current stack.
  public static string CurrentStackString
  {
    get { return string.Join(" ", CurrentStack.Reverse()); }
  }
}
```

(`ImmutableStack` is available [here](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable)). You can then use it like this:

```
static async Task SomeWork()
{
  using (MyStack.Push())
  {
    ...
    Console.WriteLine(MyStack.CurrentStackAsString + ": Hi!");
  }
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it works with *all* `async` code: fork/join, custom awaitables, `ConfigureAwait(false)`, etc. The disadvantage is that you're adding some overhead. Also, this approach **only works on .NET 4.5**; the logical call context on .NET 4.0 is not `async`-aware and will **not** work correctly.

**Update:** I released a [NuGet package (described on my blog)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/announcement-async-diagnostics.html) that uses PostSharp to inject the pushes and pops automatically. So getting a good trace should be a lot simpler now.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I'd add to your note about unreliable call stacks that in the case of inlining optimizations or tail call optimizations, the thing on the top of the call stack might be the *caller's* caller. So you can't even rely on it in many "simple" scenarios.

Comment: This answer is more a statement towards stacktraces in general, and doesn't really acknowledge what has been asked.

Visual Studio does exactly what was asked, so it isn't unreasonable to wonder how it was accomplished, and wanting the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice nuget extension for this by the async/await king.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncStackTraceEx/

you need to change your await call from

```
Await DownloadAsync(url)
```

to

```
Await DownloadAsync(url).Log()
```

Finally, in the catch block, just call

```
ex.StackTraceEx()
```

One important note:  This method can only be called once and ex.StackTrace must not be evaluated before.  It seems that the stack can only be read once.