# Await with .NET 4.0: meaningful stack traces

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a C# console application project using .NET 4.0, with the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package installed. I use this code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo().Wait();
    }

    static void Log(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    private static async Task Foo()
    {
        try
        {
            await DoSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
        }
    }

    private static async Task DoSomething()
    {
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside of the Log method, I get my DivideByZero exception, but the stack trace I see is:

```
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at AsyncStacks.Program.<Foo>d__0.MoveNext() in p:\Sandbox\AsyncStacks\AsyncStacks\Program.cs:line 25
```

This stack trace is next to useless as it doesn't tell me where the exception was actually thrown.

If I change my project to target .NET 4.5, I get a more useful exception:

```
at AsyncStacks.Program.<DoSomething>d__3.MoveNext() in p:\Sandbox\AsyncStacks\AsyncStacks\Program.cs:line 35
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at AsyncStacks.Program.<Foo>d__0.MoveNext() in p:\Sandbox\AsyncStacks\AsyncStacks\Program.cs:line 25
```

How can I get a useful stack trace from a .NET 4.0 project when using `await`?

**Update**

The "old" [AsyncTargetingPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack) does throw a much better stack trace. The issue seems to have been introduced in the "new" [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a good stack trace with .NET async methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410661/is-it-possible-to-get-a-good-stack-trace-with-net-async-methods)

Answer (score 7):

Changing `Foo` to this appears to get a better result:

```
private static async Task Foo()
{
    await DoSomething().ContinueWith(t => Log(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

**Update: However, the downside is you have to use the same `.ContinueWith` every time you use the `await` keyword. I.e., if you await something that also awaits, you need to `.ContinueWith` that too.**

Comment: +1 for both question and answer - however, I think your meant `Log(t.Exception.InnerException)`