# Identify log entries across a series of async operations

Tags: c#, logging, asynchronous

I have seen in the past people associating log entries on thread ID; an imperfect solution, but one that worked in many cases. Having started doing async programming in c#, I am curious what is the best way to handle logging across multiple async operations. So an example:

```
async Task<string> GetSongNameAsync(byte [] songBytes, AuthInfo auth)
{    
    Log("Received request from user " + auth.User);
    if (!await Authentication.HasPremiumAccountAsync(auth)) // More logging in here
    {
        return "Error: Your subscription does not support this feature";
    }

    Song song = await SongIdentifier.IdentifyAsync(songBytes); // Even more logging here
    if (song != null)
    {
        return song.ToString()
    }

    return new Song() {Name = "Never Gonna Give You Up", Artist = "Rick Astley", Notes = "You just got rick-rolled!"};
}
```

If there is an error in the auth logic or the song ID logic, I'd like to associate the error with the particular request, so that I can query my logging database and see somewhat-sequentially how the request was handled, and maybe why it failed. I could start passing around a Guid or something like that, and include that in the message, but it seems somewhat cumbersome to make every constructor and object expose this value, when I really want it at the async equivalent of 'thread local storage'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Task.Id` ,and the static `Task.CurrentId` in a somewhat similar way to `Thread.Id`, but it doesn't really play along with async\await as you can see  [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/taskcurrentid-in-async-methods.html).
I think the best approach is to identify each request you receive in a unique way, either by attaching a requestId to it (or to the base class), using something provided by the infrastucture (in WCF this would be `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.MessageId`), or by using the exact tick (maybe with thread id) when the request was received as the ID.

---

BTW this is also a nice solution if your request is handled across a distributed system

---

Regarding your comment..

You can:

```
public static class MagicalHelpper
{
private static ConditionalWeakTable<object, int> _registry = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, int>();

public void GetId(object obj)
{
 int result = _registry.GetValue(obj, ((object key)=> DateTime.Now.Ticks +   
                                                  Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
  return result;

}
}
```

this was written without a compiler...

Now whenever you want, you can just go `MagicalHelpper.GetId(something)` just remember to stick to the same request object...

This should be compleatly thread safe, and not cause any memory leak.
ConditionalWeakTable documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx

Comment: Having an identifier for the task isn't a problem, but can I attach it in some way that library code can just call `Log(Task.CustomIdentifier + "/SongTooShort")`, and regardless of how the library code was called is guaranteed to match up to the caller's identifier?

Answer (score 0):

There's a large MSDN article on this subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx). There's no simple solution, but it describes one method of doing this using `ExecutionContext` and thread local storage. There's some example code of this. Caveats apply though.

There's also an alternative answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410661/is-it-possible-to-get-a-good-stack-trace-with-net-async-methods) if you're running .Net 4.5