# DoAsync with Rx

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, system.reactive, async-await

First, is there an implementation like "DoAsync" to use with Rx? Considering that I have a specific `SynchronizationContext` and `IScheduler` using the same thread, some like https://gist.github.com/OmerMor/1554548

Now, see the code below:

```
  public static IObservable<T> DoAsyncWithFallBack<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task> accessor, Action<T, Exception> localizedFallback)
    {
        return new AnonymousObservable<T>(obs =>
        {
            return source.Subscribe(async x =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await accessor(x);
                    obs.OnNext(x);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    localizedFallback(x, ex);
                    obs.OnError(ex);
                }
            }, obs.OnError, obs.OnCompleted);
        });
    }
```

and the usage (just for example):

```
   Observable.Return(1)
             .ObserveOn(scheduler)
             .Select(a => new
                             {
                                 EventData = a,
                                 Task = TaskEx.Run(() => DoSomething(a))
                             })
             .DoAsyncWithFallBack(async a => await a.Task, (a, ex) => FallBackPlan(a.EventData, ex))
             .Subscribe(next => {}, ex => {});
```

Using this code above, if I get an exception, the stack trace does not help me at all, I lose the information about the DoSomething method, what would be the right way to get it?

If you search a little you can find some problems about exceptions with async/await:
[Is it possible to get a good stack trace with .NET async methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410661/is-it-possible-to-get-a-good-stack-trace-with-net-async-methods)

Comment: Look at the ExceptionDispatchInfo class

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: VS2013 is supposed to have [improved that.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/01/debugging-asynchronous-code-in-visual-studio-2013-call-stack-enhancements.aspx)

Comment: @NedStoyanoy VS 2012 and .NET 4.0

Comment: @HamletHakobyan this class is only available in .NET 4.5 +

Answer (score 1):

For .NET 4.0, your best bet is to wrap the exception before passing it to `OnError`.  This will preserve the stack trace of the exception.

```
obs.OnError(new ApplicationException("Error in DoAsync", ex));
```