How to get calling methods from DbUpdateConcurrencyException
I want to log the call stack when DbUpdateConcurrencyException is thrown. It is thrown when I call DbContext.SaveChangesAsync.
However, the stack trace does not show the calling chain of methods, it starts with SaveChangesAsync in my code and goes up into the EfCore implementation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.<ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyExceptionAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.<ConsumeResultSetAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.<ConsumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__106.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__110.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
   at MyProject.MyContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__180.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyContext.cs:line 315

I call SaveChangesAsync from multiple places in my code, and one of places where it fails occasionally would be
        public async Task SaveChangesAsyncCallerToReproduceTheProblem()
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException e)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug(e, "Failed to update...");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogDebug(e, "Failed to update...");

                throw;
            }
        }

and the SaveChangesAsync on my context would also be pretty standard
        public override async Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            SetUpdatedAt();

            await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        }

, so, in this case, I would expect to see UpdateOrder in the stack trace and others calling it - up to the controller - and further non-interesting to me methods.
If I set a breakpoint and check the exception, it does not have an inner exception on it

My app is a .Net 7 web app and I inject context on Startup.ConfigureServices
            services.AddDbContext<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);
            });

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to see my calling methods? Would it be introducing inefficiency if there is a solution?
Edited: I deployed a test app that reproduces the exception into Azure and App Insights have 2 lines for the exception: one similar to the above I have locally and another one having a more complete stack trace which has the calling methods. This does not solve the original problem but is good enough for us to understand what is happening, so, I will not be spending much time investigating it.
For those who want to dig deeper - a possible problem might be due to the call stack for async calls, thanks @Progman for the suggestion. The link from their comment: Is it possible to get a good stack trace with .NET async methods?
Edited 2 Renamed method that calls SaveChangesAsync to SaveChangesAsyncCallerToReproduceTheProblem as the previous name was very obviously a code smell, thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos

The last line in your stack trace is at MyProject.MyContext.d__180.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\MyProject\MyContext.cs:line 315 - which method is on line 315?

You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410661/is-it-possible-to-get-a-good-stack-trace-with-net-async-methods

line 315 is the closing bracket on MyContext.SaveChangeAsync. I think @Progman

I think @Progman is right. I deployed a test app to Azure which reproduces the exception and it gives 2 lines for this exception - one with the limited chain I put into the question and another one is more complete and includes the methods that are in the calling chain - which hints there is a possibility. But after I figured the info is in Azure, the problem became of less importance and I will probably not be looking into it.

also be pretty standard most definitely not. The question's code is a strong smell, suggesting an antipattern was used.  DbContext is a Unit-of-Work and SaveChanges commits all the changes in all managed entities. Your "UpdateOrders" will delete 47 Products and update 62 customers if they were loaded and modified in the same Unit-of-Work, ie DbContext instance.

On top of this, there's no acceptAllChangesOnSuccess overload. That's just not how EF works. EF uses optimistic concurrency. Instead of locking database rows while a client application works with the data, the way computers did in the 1980s and mid 1990s, optimistic concurrency assumes there's a very low chance of other clients modifying the same rows. Instead of locking the rows, it checks to ensure they weren't modified. This is quite similar to the snapshot isolation or multi-version model used by PostegreSQL by the way.

@PanagiotisKanavos yes, updating order method name is misleading, but it is outside of the problem in the question. I was talking about SaveChangesAsync and what I saw in some other products it is pretty standard. I can update the question to exclude this specific part.

The change check is made either by comparing the original object values against those found in the database. By default all fields are compared. In SQL Server, an automatic rowversion  column can be used to avoid comparing all fields. If SetUpdatedAt modifies the original values, EF will think the database was changed and throw an exception. Without knowing what SetUpdatedAt does, one can only guess.

@Mykola outside of the problem not at all and no, none of this is standard. There are bad articles and bad examples that use such code, but that doesn't make it standard. A DbConcurrencyException is thrown when EF detects that the stored data was changed. That can happen if some other connection did change it (in which case there's nothing to fix) or if the custom code breaks the concurrency model by modifying the wrong data. We can't even guess what all those custom methods are doing. There's no SaveChangesAsync(bool,CancellationToken) method.

@PanagiotisKanavos re: acceptAllChangesOnSuccess - this is also not part of the question. We are happy to have the exception when data was changed by somebody else. We just want some extra info on when it happens. I am sorry I gave this bit of code, it was a test project used to investigate the specific problem of the call stack and I used an existing project with existing code that used a no-sql db

@PanagiotisKanavos re: SaveChangesAsync overload design code smell - do you possibly have a link to an article describing good design please?

@Mykola in that case you asked the completely wrong question. This has nothing to do with the exception or the stack trace. You're asking how to find the changes that caused the error. Those are available in the DbContext.Entries property. This is documented in the Handling Concurrency Exceptions page, in the Resolving Concurrency Conflicts section.

The standard way to handle such issues, even back in the 1990s when optimistic concurrency was introduced, was to check the actual and current values and decide what to do. Perhaps you can just retry, thus overwriting the stored changes. Perhaps you should tell the user the data changed, load the new data and let them work with it. Perhaps you could show them the values side-by-side and let them decide which to keep. There's no one-size-fits-all, that's a business decision

On the other hand, using the wrong concurrency check can cause failures even when none occurred. Date fields are problematic because they have a limited precision. It's quite possible for 2 or more changes to occur in the same second or even microsecond. SQL Server's datetime field has a precision of just 3ms. A rowversion field on the other hand is an incrementing integer managed by the database so there's no way 2 connections will get the same rowversion values when storing changes. A GUID is better than a datetime field because it's guaranteed to be unique.

@PanagiotisKanavos yes, I am not asking about how to handle the exception. You've said earlier the override version of SaveChangesAsync is not standard, so, I am asking about it. Maybe "standard" is not 100% correct word, but I do not want our SaveChangesAsync override to be an obvious code smell.

Did you try to adapt the code from Gerald Barre's 7 year old article ? That code does not change the entities themselves, it only creates new entries to an append-only Audit table, so there's no chance of concurrency conflicts.   The same thing can be done nowadays using a SaveChanges interceptor
