# Define a custom exception format for logging

Tags: c#, exception, logging

I regularly have a requirement:

## How do I log an exception with as much information I need but as little text as possible?

The `exception.Message` has too little information, of course.

But `exception.ToString()` is a bit too much and unreadable:

```
System.NotImplementedException: Die Methode oder der Vorgang ist nicht implementiert.
   bei ConsoleApplication1.Program.Second() in C:\..\Program.cs:Line 48.
   bei ConsoleApplication1.Program.First() in C:\..\Program.cs:Line 43.
   bei ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\..\Program.cs:Line 21.
```

My idea is a pretty single line with the most relevant information, something like this:

```
System.NotImplementedException: Die Methode oder der Vorgang ist nicht implementiert {ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)[21] -> ConsoleApplication1.Program.First()[43] -> ConsoleApplication1.Program.Second()[48]}
```

What would be the best way to get this? 
I realized that I could get the deepest exception causing method name from the TargetSite Property.
But how to get the methods between? And the most important thing: How to get the line numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the links of @data I make my own method, which meets my demands.

```cs
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return a compact exception format for logging
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// In a single line the exception will contains the most relevant information like
    /// Excepition type and message, the call stack methods and lines
    /// Note: call stack is only available in Debug, Release will not contain these information
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="ex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <example>System.NotImplementedException: NotImplementedException (OwnLib.WoohooClass.ThisIsTheBestMethodEver()[13] => ConsoleApplication1.OwnClass.CallMeAClass()[13] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.Second(System.TimeSpan)[68] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.First()[57] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])[25])</example>
    public static string ToCompactString(this Exception ex)
    {
        var stack = new List<string>();
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        for (int i = 0; i < stackTrace.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            StackFrame sf = stackTrace.GetFrame(i);
            var method = sf.GetMethod();
            stack.Add(string.Format("{0}[{1}]", 
                method.ToString().SubstringFromMatch(method.Name, true).Replace(method.Name, string.Format("{0}.{1}", method.ReflectedType.FullName, method.Name)), 
                sf.GetFileLineNumber()));
        }

        return string.Format("{0}: {1} ({2})", ex.GetType(), ex.Message, stack.GetDelimiterSeperatedList(" => "));
    }
}

//Helper methods
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Substring for a searched string. takes the whole string from the match and cuts before.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="searchString">string to search within</param>
    /// <param name="searchedString">string to search for</param>
    /// <param name="includeMatch"><c>true</c> = with searchString, <c>false</c> = without</param>
    /// <param name="count">which time to found (0 = first)</param>
    /// <returns>a substring for a match, the whole string when no match</returns>
    public static string SubstringFromMatch(this string searchString, string searchedString, bool includeMatch, int count = 0)
    {
        if (searchString.Contains(searchedString))
        {
            var index = searchString.IndexOf(searchedString, count, StringComparison.Ordinal) + (includeMatch ? 0 : searchedString.Length);
            return searchString.Substring(index, searchString.Length - index);
        }
        return searchString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list auf values, concatted by a delimiter like ",", e.g. "1,2,abc,cde"
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>a maximum of 999 items could be seperated</remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="list"></param>
    /// <param name="delimiter">a delimiter used to seperate the items</param>
    /// <example>"," => "item1,item2,item3"; " - " "item1 - item2 - item3"</example>
    public static string GetDelimiterSeperatedList<T>(this ICollection<T> list, string delimiter)
    {
        if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
        {
            var seperatedList = String.Empty;
            var listCounter = 0;
            foreach (var id in list)
            {
                seperatedList += String.Format("{0}{1}", id, delimiter);
                if (listCounter++ >= 999) break;
            }
            return seperatedList.Remove(seperatedList.LastIndexOf(delimiter, StringComparison.Ordinal));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

An example output looks like this:

> System.NotImplementedException: You have forgotton to do something (AnotherLib.WoohooClass.ThisIsTheMostUselessMethodEver()[13] => ConsoleApplication1.AnotherClass.CallMeAClass()[13] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.Third(System.TimeSpan)[68] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.Second()[63] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.First()[57] => ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])[25])

By the way: I also validated the time measurement of my solution above and the the normal `exception.ToString()` method. It was interesting that there is no significant difference.

Thanks at all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine information from `exception.Message` with [`Environment.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (for example, split into lines and use only couple of the last ones) or use [`Diagnostics.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get only the inforomation you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As far as exceptions are concerned TMI is a YMMV thing.
I'd go with the Exception.Message + StackTrace. (pretty much what ToString() seems to print)

If you really think you only need the last couple of functions/only functions from user code you can split the stack trace and only get the lines that match your class/assembly name.

IMO more info is always good, and no space saving/time spent skipping a few lines during reading is worth the developer frustration/time spent of

> Wow, what's going on in this piece of code, I wish I had one more line from the stack trace.

To get the line numbers you need the pdb file info:
[C# Exceptions Not Giving Line Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191957/c-sharp-exceptions-not-giving-line-numbers)

Comment: @Max the links in my answer will give you access to StackTrace in a manner that will enable you to print the error in a way you want :)