# Line numbers not printing in error logs

Tags: c#, error-handling, exception

I have an exception handling attribute for the controller that writes error logs for every exception that comes in the program. I have .pdb file deployed on the server and have below code to written for the line numbers:

```
// Get stack trace for the exception with source file information
var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
// Get the top stack frame
var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
// Get the line number from the stack frame
var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
```

Still I get line number as 0.

I have two questions on this:

1. Shouldn't the line numbers get automatically written if I keep the .pdb file on the server?
2. Why am I getting them as 0 in the above code?

I referred to [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a58dc2a0-0612-407b-8cbe-10f1784ba85a/how-to-retreive-the-line-number-and-file-name-of-c-source-code?forum=csharplanguage), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328990/c-sharp-get-line-number-which-thrown-exception).

Appreciate your reply.

Comment: Not always; despite having the PDB the code may be so optimized to make it impossible to associate particular point in the stack to any one line number in source.

Comment: @Jenish: I already have the .pdb in place with the binaries on server.

Comment: @Peter: What other option do I have?

Comment: @Mustafa did you check ex.StackTrace (string) does contain line number or not?

Comment: @Jenish: No they don't. I print complete stack trace but there are no line numbers in that.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya the OP says that line number 0 is returned and that the PDB file is with the binaries, asking/telling things already detailed does not seem useful.

Comment: @Mustafa You can either try debugging in another way (trace, logging, etc.) or try deploying DEBUG binaries that will have more accurate line numbers.

Comment: @Mustafa this answer may be helpful to you for release pdb files http://stackoverflow.com/a/628590/1505865