# How can we get user define object in Exception in catch

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, stack-trace

We want to get user defined data that has been caused exception eg. Index out of bound exception.

```
try
{
    int[] list = new int[2];
    list[0] = 1;
    list[1] = 2;
    list[3] = 3;
    Console.WriteLine(list[4]);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    /* Expected
     1) Line Number :5
     2) Method Name: SearchArray()
     3) Data: 3 // object specifically
     4) excetion message:ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.
    */
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
    StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

    var data = ex.StackTrace;
    var tr = ex.HResult;
}
```

In this scenario, we want to get List[3] value because this line is responsible for the exception (where list[3] will not be accessed).

Comment: you can use ex.Message to print your exception

Comment: Do you want to get string "list[3] = 3;" somehow from exception object?

Comment: I see your expectation now. What you asking is available from stack trace (source filename, line number, etc.), but will reliably work only in DEBUG builds because in RELEASE build some "optimization" mechanics take place, and some of your code may be even optimized-out.

Comment: You cannot get the value of `list[3]` because it is undefined. The array `list` contains only two elements.

Comment: no..ex.message does not give us proper data.i want the exact data when error triggered

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [How do I get the line number of an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328990/c-sharp-get-line-number-which-threw-exception)?

Comment: I dont want only line number ..i want the object of data that has been exception trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Since scope of your code is outside catch statement, you cannot access the object there.
As an alternate you can user StackTrace of exception. It will give you line number after column ":". You can use it. however, It will be Line number of class where error is occurred and not the exact function.

Comment: can i get object in this e.g. list in catch without passing list in the catch.

Comment: No its not possible as list is defined in try. In order to access it in catch, you need to define your object outside of try.int[] list = new int[2];
            try
            {
                
                list[0] = 1;
                list[1] = 2;
                list[3] = 3;
                Console.WriteLine(list[4]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {Error Handling}

Comment: if list define out side of try  then how do we get that ?

Comment: Exception will not give you exact object but access to object. You need to identify the error on mentioned line number. As the error in your code is logical not a compile time error. Logical error are like doing Multiplication where you are asked to do a subtraction. Hope it clarifies.