# How to get error line number using try/catch in java?

Tags: java

I want to find out the error line number using try and catch. I tried to get some information from [How to get error line number of code using try-catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338495/how-to-get-error-line-number-of-code-using-try-catch), but it didn't help since I use different language.

Now, I am getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` when I do

```
try {
    // My Code Here

} catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
}
```

I tried printing `e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());` as well, but it seems like it's not showing the correct error line number. Is there any way I can get it easily? I have a pretty big file and I don't think I'll be able to go over line by line to figure out what's wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a Logger library, it can print the stack trace in debug mode that points to the line number. else printStackTrace() is your friend.

```
try {
    // My Code Here

} catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
      e.printStackTrace();  // This will give line number
}
```

Comment: Whoa! `.printStackTrace()`!!! I didn't even know if such a thing existed. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
package com.ms.common;

public class Run {

public static void main(String[] args) {
try {

  int value = 5;
  int divider = 0;

  int result = value / divider;

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getStackTrace()[0]);
}

}

}
```

**Error at Run.java at line# 11**

```
com.ms.common.Run.main(Run.java:11)
```