# How to show line numbers in stack trace if single file is produced

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, pdb-files

ASP.NET 5 MVC application uses single file publishing method for deployment:

[image]

In this case stack trace does not contain line numbers. If

> [v]Produce single file

Checkbox is unchecked, line numbers are shown.
How to enable line numbers if single file is published ?

I tried to set Debug information  Full to in Advanced build setting

[image]

and

changed project file as described in [Show line number in exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688336/show-line-number-in-exception-handling) to

```
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
```

but line numbers are still not shown if published to single file.
Visual Studio 2019 IDE is used to publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems like a known [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39987) and it's not closed even in recent (net6.0 as I'm writing it) .net versions. Our team is suffering from this issue too.

Although making the single file publication with .pdb files attached helps, it's writing something like:

```
<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
```

in your csproj file, more on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#include-pdb-files-inside-the-bundle).

But it's not clear if it's should be a default behaviour